# Transferring Files via TCP/IP works in Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: java, sockets, ubuntu, windows-7, tcp

I was trying my hands at sending multiple files using TCP/IP connection with the help of [this guide](https://coderanch.com/t/595892/java/Transfer-Multiple-File-problems-socket).

When I execute my testClient codes from Ubuntu 14.04, files are transferred over to testServer in Windows 7. The .txt files received here are in correct format.

However, when I execute testClients codes from Windows 7 and testServer from Ubuntu 14.04, the files received in Ubuntu 14.04 was messed up. (The contents from txt#2 contents spill over to txt#1.)

During the swap, none of the codes in both testServer and testClients were changed other than their IP address and file location.

I am confused. Why did the codes work fine in Windows 7 but not in Ubuntu? Is there something wrong with my codes? I would appreciate any help on this.

**TestServer.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    OutputStream output;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    int len;
    int smblen; 
    InputStream in;
    boolean flag = true;
    DataInputStream clientData;
    BufferedInputStream clientBuff;

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5991);
    serverSocket.setSoTimeout(500000);
    System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Just connected to " + clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

    while (true){
        while(flag==true) {  
            in = clientSocket.getInputStream();   
            clientData = new DataInputStream(in);  
            clientBuff = new BufferedInputStream(in); 

            int fileSize = clientData.read();
            if (fileSize != 0)
                System.out.println("Receiving " + fileSize + " files.\n");  

            //Store filenames and file sizes from client directory
            ArrayList<File>files=new ArrayList<File>(fileSize); 
            ArrayList<Integer>sizes = new ArrayList<Integer>(fileSize); 

            //Server accepts filenames
            for (int count=0; count<fileSize; count ++){
                File ff=new File(clientData.readUTF());
                files.add(ff);
            }

            for (int count=0; count<fileSize; count ++){
                sizes.add(clientData.readInt());
            }

            for (int count=0; count<fileSize; count++) {

                if (fileSize - count == 1) {
                    flag = false;
                }

                len = sizes.get(count);

                output = new FileOutputStream("/home/pp/Desktop/inResources/" + files.get(count));
                dos = new DataOutputStream(output);
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(output);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  

                bos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length); 

                while (len > 0 && (smblen = clientData.read(buffer)) > 0) { 
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, smblen); 
                    len = len - smblen;
                    dos.flush();
                }  
                dos.close();  

                System.out.println("File " + files.get(count) + " with " + sizes.get(count) + " bytes recieved.");
            }

        }

        if (flag == false) {
            System.out.println("\nTransfer completed. Closing socket...");
            serverSocket.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**TestClient.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String serverName = "192.168.1.12"; //IP address
    int port = 5991;

    Socket sock = new Socket(serverName, port);
    System.out.println("Connected to " + serverName + " on port " + port + "\n");  


    File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\inter2\\Desktop\\noobs\\outResources");
    File[] files = myFile.listFiles();

    OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();  
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os); 

    //Sending total number of files in folder
    dos.writeInt(files.length);

    //Sending file names
    for (int count=0; count<files.length; count++) {
        dos.writeUTF(files[count].getName());
    }

    //Sending file sizes
    for (int count=0; count<files.length; count++) {
        int filesize = (int) files[count].length();
        dos.writeInt(filesize);
    }

    //Sending of files
    for (int count=0; count<files.length; count ++) {
        int filesize = (int) files[count].length();
        byte [] buffer = new byte [filesize];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[count].toString());  
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);  

        //Sending file name and file size to the server  
        bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); 

        dos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);   
        dos.flush(); 


        System.out.println("Sending file " + files[count].getName() + " with " + filesize + " bytes.");
    }  

    System.out.println("\n" + files.length + " files successfully transfered.");
    sock.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code never worked.

```
int fileSize = clientData.read();
```

Here you are reading the *amount* of files, as a `byte`.

```
dos.writeInt(files.length)
```

Here you are writing that amount, as an `int`. So already your writer is three bytes ahead of your reader.

Change `read()` to `readInt()` above.

Other notes:

Receiving:

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

This is OK but a bigger buffer would be more efficient, say 8192.

```
 bos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

This is a bug. Remove it. You are writing 1024 null bytes at the beginning of the file.

```
 while (len > 0 && (smblen = clientData.read(buffer)) > 0) { 
     dos.write(buffer, 0, smblen); 
     len = len - smblen;
     dos.flush();
```

Don't flush inside loops.

```
 }
```

Sending:

```
    byte [] buffer = new byte [filesize];

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[count].toString());  
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);  

    //Sending file name and file size to the server  
    bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); 

    dos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

No need to waste a buffer of the size of the file. Use the same code you use for receiving above.